# JavaScript function can't be run in external file

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two functions in external file, then I call A and B in HEAD script, and A can be run and B can't, but if I put B into head script, B also can be run. I am not sure why, what can I do?

HTML:

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function B(id) {
    var selected = document.getElementById(id)
    var arr = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text.split(" ");
    var value = ""
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (value != "") value = value + " ";
        value = value + arr[i];
    }
    return value;
}

function save() {
    A("msg");
    var x = B(id);
}
-->
...
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/my.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

my.js:

```
function A(msg) {
    scroll(0,0);
    var outerPane = document.getElementById('FreezePane');
    var innerPane = document.getElementById('InnerFreezePane');
    if (outerPane) outerPane.className = 'FreezePaneOn';
    if (innerPane) innerPane.innerHTML = msg;
}

function B(id) {
    var selected = document.getElementById(id)
    var arr = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text.split(" ");
    var value = ""
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (value != "") value = value + " ";
        value = value + arr[i];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `language` attribute, try to avoid using `type` attribute when possible (just use `<script>...</script>`) and definitely do not put HTML comments (the `<!-- ... -->`) inside a `<script>` tag, as that will either cause a JavaScript syntax error, or treat it as a comment and prevent it from loading.

Comment: There are such tags, I hide them for less code here. I also removed `<!--...-->`, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest thing to do is wrap the code in the head in a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) handler like this...

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
      // your external files are guaranteed to be loaded now
      // you can call A or B
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

`onload` is only fired after all external scripts have been loaded.

Here is a full example...

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello world</title>
<script>
function save() {
  A()
  B()
}

window.onload = function() {
  save()
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
<script src="./external.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**external.js**

```
function A() {
  alert('A ran')
}

function B() {
  alert('B ran')
}
```

**NOTE:** This is better than moving the external script to the head, like the other answers suggest, because external resources loaded in the head block the entire page render until they are loaded.

By leaving the external script at the end of the body tag, the page load will seem faster as the css/html will display immediately. Even if the javascript isn't loaded yet.

Comment: do you mean 'window.onload = save() {A("msg"); var x = B(id);}'?

Comment: another option is to leave `save` as is and just call it inside `window.onload = function () { save(); }`

Comment: are you sure? function not be run, can you show me more detail?

Comment: `window.onload = function () { save(); }` has the same result with my code.

Comment: Check your javascript console. I bet you have an error. Most likely, `id` is not defined. Because the execution stops on the error, B is not executed

Comment: Check my edit. Added a full example. I have confirmed this works

Comment: I found there is no function B in F12 Developer console, I also reboot my local tomcat and found B is file of tomcat run env, do you know why? by the way, save() will be run after click button save.

Comment: I found why, because function name!  In fact, function `B()` is `getSelectedName()`, it is ok after modified it to `GetSelectedName()`. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add your external file before the script tag contains your "save" function.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src = "yourfile.js" type="text/JavaScript">
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   function save(){
           A();
           B();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: you know function A is at the same place with B, but A is no problem to be run. then even if I put file before save, same result.